# TinyMCE: Move cursor to end of inserted text

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-3

I have insert a line break within TinyMCE

`tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, "<br/>");`

However the cursor currently stays where it was before.. which makes sense, however I would like code which moves the cursor the end of the html I just inserted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a space after the `<br/>` will reposition the cursor:

So change:

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, "<br/>");
```

to

```
tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, "<br/> ");
```

Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PbKQpJ  (demo links above editor)